# Библиотека для работы с IMAP

Tags: .net, imap

Как без помощи сторонних *.net*-библиотек работать с входящей почтой по протоколу *IMAP*?

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже воспользовался библиотекой LumiSoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ из комментария:

Насколько я знаю .net framework не содержит реализации из коробки. Не смотрели в сторону open-source библиотек? http://codeproject.com/Articles/8008/IMAP-Client-library-using-C